# Moving repeated files from one folder to another

Tags: php, file, file-system

I want to scan my whatsapp images folder and move all the repeated images to folder named recycle bin to delete them later:

```
<?php

$dir    = 'C:\wamp\www\whatsapp';
$files = scandir($dir);

$x = 0;

foreach($files as $f1)
{

    $crc1 = strtoupper(dechex(crc32(file_get_contents("whatsapp/".$f1))));

    unset($files[$x]);

    $j = 0;

    foreach($files as $f2)
    {

        $crc2 = strtoupper(dechex(crc32(file_get_contents("whatsapp/".$f2))));

        if($crc1 == $crc2){

            rename("whatsapp/".$f2, "recycle bin/".$f2);

            unset($files[$j]);
        }

        $j++;
    }

    $x++;
}

exit('Done');
```

Does this code seems to be trusted to move only the repeated images without any mistakes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you try with this pseudocode:

- get files list from directory
- declare array for crc
- for each file in directory
- **check if the mime content type is correct**
- get crc for file
- check if this crc is in array for crc
- if is in array move it
- else push crc into array

Thanks Pimgd. You are right. I should write it on the beginning. First of all there is only one loop, so if you have a lot of files, it will be faster. Second, it checks content file, so you will not touch not image files. Third, the code will be more clear.

Comment: Why would this pseudo code be a better algorithm than what the asker currently has? (Please add some explanation)